# concatenating two string dynamically with loading images

Tags: javascript, string, image-loading, dynamic-binding

I am trying to load more than thousand images on page load and I want images to be played in presentation when 1/3 of the images has been loaded. Its working perfectly till now. but I want to add rest of the images in the queue after loading them. We can say buffering like happening in videos.

This has been done so far:

```
 $(img).one('load', function(e){
     op.imageCounter++;
     layout='<img src="'+this.src+'" class="img">'+layout;

     if(op.imageCounter > (op.images*0.7)) {
         $('#loader').removeClass('loader');
         reversedLayout = layout.split(">").reverse().join("");
         newLayout = reversedLayout.replace(/img"/gi,'img">');
         $('.imageplayer').prepend(newLayout);
         console.log(newLayout);

         if(flag == true) {
             $('.imageplayer').prepend(newLayout);   //this will trigger play. it will start to play 1/3 of images in queue while rest of other will be downloading
             layout = '';
             flag = false;
         } else {   //after playing them here I am trying to append rest of others to that queue but it causes start presentation from first image
             $('.imageplayer').prepend(newLayout);
             newLayout += layout;
             layout = '';
         }
         imgPlay();
     }                 
     imageLoader();
 });
```

It will be great help if someone could give the solution. Thanx in Advance!!